# Dispatch first bloc event or cubit method, on page start inside StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I have 10 buttons in main menu of my app and each of them contains BlocBuilder inside them.

So when I click on those buttons to open a new page, I want to dispatch the first event, but I don't know how. I can change all classes to stateful widget and then call **bloc.dispatch(event)** inside **initialState()** function, but I would like to discover another way, and not sure whether it's the best way

Comment: Pls, show your code so we can know where to start from

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to trigger the first event/method call inside BlocBuilder I had to add **bloc** argument and give parameter provided my BlocProvider, only after this I managed to call my method.

```
BlocBuilder<MyCubit, MyState>(
      bloc: BlocProvider.of<MyCubit>(context)..myFunction(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, state) {
//Your code...
}
```

Comment: But first state is missing in blocListener

Comment: For me I had to add the `bloc` argument.

Answer (score 3):

you can use .. operator to add event while declaring like

```
BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => FirstBloc()..add(InitialiEvent()), // <-- first event, 
            child: BlocBuilder<FirstBloc, FirstState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, state) {
                ...
              },
            ),
```

or you can do it inside the `initState` method as well

Comment: It can still be achieved without using a statefull widget. as it is adviced to avoid statefull widget as much as possible thus if the need for using a statefull widget is not there, leave it as stateless

Comment: It didn't work, maybe because my BlocProvider wrapping MaterialApp. In my case BlocProvider is not wrapping BlocBuilder as in your example

Comment: you mean like this.? 
```BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => ProfileBloc(ProfileLoading()),
        // lazy: ,
        child: Consumer<BaseModel>(
          builder: (context, basemodel, _) {
            return MaterialAppWidget();
          },
        ),
      ),```
@SardorbekRkh

Comment: if yes then you can do like ```BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context).add(ProfileInitialEvent());```. This also adds the initial event to the bloc where you want to use that bloc.
Thanks.